# Zynq SOC sending raw ethernet packets to a Desktop doesnot work through a switch

Tags: fpga, ethernet, zynq

I have developed Xilinx Zynq SoC c program for transmitting customized raw ethernet packets for testing purpose.

When I connect the Zynq SoC board with a **patch cable** to the Desktop I get the following packet on Wireshark.

[WireShark Packet Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miRXg.png)

But when I bring a switch in between the two i.e. Zynq SoC connected to the switch and Desktop connected to the same switch the above packet sent from Zynq SoC isn't visible on Wireshark.

Can someone point me out what's wrong in the packet I am sending that makes the switch reject the packet I am sending.

I would like to mention that the zynq board doesn't transmit any packets except from the above.

Thanks

Comment: How often does it transmit the packet? 
Is the link up and running from the ZynQ to the switch? I.e. is the link auto-negotiated correctly? Can you access the switch and read the packet counters on each port?

Comment: Also, can you post original ethernet frame you're sending? Wireshark won't show some fields (like FCS) that's processed and omitted at nic level.

Comment: It could be that the switch is not routing the packet because it does not think that the destination address is on the port that you are monitoring.